# ng-change event in datetimepicker not calling in angular js

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I have included below datetimepicker

```
 <datetimepicker
                                                    ng-change="setStartDateSlider"
                                                    hour-step="hourStep"
                                                    minute-step="minuteStep"
                                                    ng-model="startFrom[$index]"
                                                    show-meridian="showMeridian"
                                                    date-format="{{format}}"
                                                    date-options="dateOptions"
                                                    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                                    datepicker-append-to-body="false"
                                                    readonly-date="false"
                                                    disabled-date="false"
                                                    hidden-time="true"
                                                    hidden-date="false"
                                                    name="datetimepicker"
                                                    show-spinners="true"
                                                    readonly-time="false"
                                                    date-opened="dateOpened"
                                                    show-button-bar="false"
                                                    placeholder="Start From"
                                    >
                            <!-- Use date-ng-click="open($event, opened)" to override date ng-click -->
                            </datetimepicker>
```

here i have mentioned the function setStartDateSlider in ng-change event.But after selecting date , it is not calling. I need selected date in this function.

Answer (score 0):

`setStartDateSlider` is a function or property? 
if it a function then you should add `()`  after the function name.

So it's looks like

```
ng-change="setStartDateSlider()"
```